# How to load dll library containing mysql functions?

Tags: c++, mysql

I create DLL library with CBuilder containing MySQL functions and then try to load this dll with LoadLibraryEx. But when i add the MySQL functions, LoadLibraryEx returns NULL pointer(library dosn`t load). In development i use MySQL functions from libMySQL.lib(that i generated from libMySQL.dll) that use libMySQL.dll durning compiling. Both modules compiles normaly. How to make library load?

Comment: "LoadLibraryEx returns NULL" means it failed. How to know why it failed? As always, call GetLastError().

Comment: Why not use the [Connector/C++ header files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/8.0/en/connector-cpp-apps-general-considerations.html#connector-cpp-apps-header-files) directly instead of loading/linking a dll?